# Permission denied visiting HTML off of server

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, ftp, vsftpd

So weird thing here, I can access my website using

ftp://username:password@192.168.1.214/godlysoftware/home.html

By obviously changing username and password to the ftp credentials.

BUT, I cannot view the website using the local machine IP

http://192.168.1.214/godlysoftware/home.html

I get Permission Denied Accessing /

This occurred after changing default root path from the /www/ in apache2 "000-default.conf" to my desire root path of my website: /godlysoftware/

Before this I was able to view the Apache 2 homepage before changing that default root directory.

I changed permissions in vsftpd.conf and only gained access through ftp and not the local IP itself.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my answer after asking around and research more.

FIRST but not recommended is:

> "here is a review of the steps to take to open up access of /var/www
>   for users (which will include the user's access when they use ftp).
>   The example gives 'myuser' access.
>
> 1. groupadd www_users
> 2. usermod -a -G www_users myuser
> 3. chown -R root:www_users /var/www
> 4. chmod -R 2775 /var/www
>
> find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0774 '{}' \; Now myuser should have
>   full access to create/remove/edit files and directories in /var/www,
>   even when they connect via ftp. The key is in the setgid bit, so that
>   group ownership is taken from the parent directory when a new file/dir
>   is created. Thus assuring all users in the group always have access."

From: [Source](https://serverfault.com/questions/288357/how-to-allow-root-login-on-vsftpd-ubuntu)

Then, after I gained FTP Access I added all my website files into /var/www/html/ and changed my homepage name to index.html, named the default one to .old.

Then I did the following command in order to give access to groups and other users read and execute only permissions along with root to have all permissions.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
```

Now if I visit my website VIA server ip: 192.169.1.214, it will show my websites home page.

> Recursively change permissions to -rwxr-xr-x.
>
> sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
>
> You should end up with the following permissions on all of the files
>   in the directory. Root: read, write, execute Group: read, execute
>   Others: read, execute
>
> Remove read permissions on the folders you don't want users in the
>   group or other to access (chmod 744 folder or chmod 700 folder). Just
>   add the -R option to do it recursively. For more information on file
>   and folder permissions, please read
>   http://catcode.com/teachmod/summary.html. There are 3 pages to read
>   through there.

From: [Source](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1204863.html)